# BMP Width/Height size over 255?

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp, image-size

As we all know each byte is unsigned char which means with a range of 0 - 255.
I wrote a code that will write BMPs, the code works.. the problem is when i try to write a bmp with width/height more then 255 it appears as a value less then 255.

On the next bit of the width i just putted `1` and it works. It outputs the real with (500) but i wish that could work for the height too.. but it doesn't. The image goes broken.

Update: Messing with height more then 214 leeds to a damaged bmp. What do i miss?
Here is my code tho:

```
typedef unsigned char  BYTE;    //1
typedef unsigned short WORD;    //2
typedef unsigned long  DWORD;   //4

typedef struct BMP_HEADER
{
    BYTE bmp_type[2];       //2
    BYTE bmp_size[4];       //4

    BYTE bmp_as[4];         //4

    BYTE bmp_offset[4];     //4
} BMP;

typedef struct DIB_HEADER
{
    BYTE dib_size[4];       //4
    DWORD dib_BMPwidth;     //4
    DWORD dib_BMPheight;        //4

    BYTE dib_BMPcplanes[2];     //2
    BYTE dib_BMPBPX[2];     //2
    BYTE dib_BIRGB[4];      //4
    BYTE dib_rawsize[4];        //4

    BYTE dib_Xresolution[4];    //4
    BYTE dib_Yresolution[4];    //4

    BYTE dib_cpalette[4];       //4
    BYTE dib_cimportant[4];     //4
} DIB;

typedef struct PIXEL_ARRAY
{
    BYTE BGR[3];            //3
} PIX;

BYTE* PAD;
DWORD padding(DWORD BMPwidth)
{
    int pitch = BMPwidth * 3;

    if (pitch % 4 != 0)
    {
        pitch += 4 - (pitch % 4);
    }

    return pitch - (BMPwidth * 3);
}

void create_bmp(char BMPname[], DWORD BMPwidth, DWORD BMPheight, WORD BMPR, WORD BMPG, WORD BMPB)
{
    // variables
    char build_name[256];
    FILE* fp;

    BMP newBMP;
    DIB newDIB;
    PIX* template;

    gedMaxGameMem = 2827465479;
    if(BMPwidth > 1 && BMPheight > 1) template = (PIX*)malloc(BMPwidth*BMPheight);
    else template = (PIX*)malloc(sizeof(PIX*)*max(BMPwidth, BMPheight));

    // make file
    sprintf(build_name, "%s.bmp", BMPname);
    fp = fopen(build_name, "wb");

    // BM
    newBMP.bmp_type[0] = 'B';
    newBMP.bmp_type[1] = 'M';   
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_type, 1, 2, fp);

    {
    // SIZE
    DWORD sz = (sizeof(newBMP) + sizeof(newDIB) + sizeof(template));
    fwrite(&sz, 1, 1, fp);
    }

    // Application specifics
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_as, 1, 4, fp);

    // offset
    newBMP.bmp_offset[0] = (sizeof(newBMP) + sizeof(newDIB));
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_offset, 1, 4, fp);

    //

    // DIB SIZE
    newDIB.dib_size[0] = sizeof(newDIB);
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_size, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Image width
    newDIB.dib_BMPwidth = BMPwidth;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPwidth, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Image height
    newDIB.dib_BMPheight = BMPheight;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPheight, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Color planes
    newDIB.dib_BMPcplanes[0] = 1;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPcplanes, 1, 2, fp);

    // DIB BMP Bits per pixel
    newDIB.dib_BMPBPX[0] = 24;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPBPX, 1, 2, fp);

    // DIB Compression method
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BIRGB, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Raw size
    newDIB.dib_rawsize[0] = sizeof(template);
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_rawsize, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Xresolution
    newDIB.dib_Xresolution[0] = 19;
    newDIB.dib_Xresolution[1] = 11;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_Xresolution, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Yresolution
    newDIB.dib_Yresolution[0] = 19;
    newDIB.dib_Yresolution[1] = 11;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_Yresolution, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Colors palette
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_cpalette, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Important colors
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_cimportant, 1, 4, fp);

    //

    {
        int i;

        for(i=0; i<BMPwidth+1; i++)
        {
            template[i].BGR[0] = BMPB;
            template[i].BGR[1] = BMPG;
            template[i].BGR[2] = BMPR;

            fwrite(template->BGR, 3, i, fp);
        }
    }

    free(template);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You appear to be writing lots of uninitialized values.  I don't see you zero-ing out the newDIB structure for example.  You just set some fields, like dib_BMPheight[0] (and sometimes dib_BMPheight[1]) but not dib_BMPheight[2] and dib_BMPheight[3].  Then you write them out, so they could be garbage.

Comment: Also be aware that stride may not match the width.  (The stride is the number of bytes from one scanline to the next.)  Each scanline must be aligned to a four-byte boundary.  That is the stride must be a multiple of 4.  Since you're writing 3 bytes per pixel, then the stride matches the width*3 only when width is a multiple of 4.

Comment: what do you mean by "uninitialized" values?
Why do i have to "zero" the newDIB strcture, i use fwrite to write as ever bytes from it i want. And also width now works, the height is giving me the problem now. If the stride log. thing can help me.. how can i use it to specificate the height's stride?

Comment: `newDIB.dib_size[0] = sizeof(newDIB); fwrite(&newDIB.dib_size, 1, 4, fp);` writes four bytes to the file, but you've only set one of them.  The other three are uninitialized.    When you instantiate a variable on the stack, its value can be anything until you explicitly set it to something.  If the variable is a struct, then you have to initialize _all_ the fields in it before you use them.

Comment: I forgot about that, thanks :) Even tho.. i succeed to do some stuff from 1 hour of reviewing the structure of BMP and my English is even bad. Now i think i have no problems with the changed initializers and padding used.

Comment: Found the problem! It don't get the things inside a new scope and after i had declrations AFTER .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fiddle with the width and height as bytes, you can't just set the second byte to one, you have to calculate the exact value, e.g.:

```
uint32_t h = 1024;

height[0] = h & 0xff;
height[1] = (h >> 8) & 0xff;
height[2] = (h >> 16) & 0xff;
height[3] = (h >> 24) & 0xff;
```

(The masking with `& 0xff` is really unneccessary here, that's done anyway when fitting the number into a byte.)

But maybe you should just use larger integer types in your structure in the first place:

```
typedef struct DIB_HEADER
{
    DWORD dib_size;
    DWORD dib_BMPwidth;
    DWORD dib_BMPheight;
    WORD dib_BMPcplanes];
    ...
};
```

(This might lead to problems with endianness, but I think Windows bitmaps are stored in Little-Endian format, so it shouldn't be an issuehere.)

**Edit**: Looking at your code a bit further, I see some errors:

- If you want to allocate temporary memory for the pixels, you must allocate 3 bytes for each pixel, i.e. `sizeof(PIX) * BMPwidth + BMWheight`. Your distinction of single-row, single columns and other bitmaps ist pointless and also introduces an error (namely not allocating the size of each pixel for each pixel.)
- You are writing a monochrome bitmap of one colour only, so you don't really need to create a huge temporary bitmap; you can write the same pixel over and over again.
- You create the `BMP` and `DIB` structures on the stack; they might therefore be uninitialised and have garbage in the fields that you don't initialise explicitly.
- You don't have to write every field on its own, you can write whole structures instead. (But you'll have to take out the `"BM"` mark, because the structure will be padded there to make the next field begin at a four-byte-border. You could also play with compiler options to always pack your structs tightly.)
- When you write out the data, you only loop over the width, but you must loop over both width and height in a nested loop.
- When you write out data with `fwrite`, your arguments are wrong: You probably want to write `fwrite(&template[i]->RGB, 3, 1, fp)`. But your item count is `i` which means that you are writing everything from the beginning over and over again, but always attaching the last byte, like ´AABABCABCDABCDE`. (This doesn't matter when all pixels have the same colour, but your file size will be off.)
- BMP line data is padded to 4 bytes.  You have written a routine for this, but don't call it.

In other words. You code isn't prepared for data that has more than one line. :-)

Here's a simpler version of your code that write a single-colour bitmap:

```
void create_bmp_uni(const char *fn, int w, int h, int r, int g, int b)
{
    FILE* fp;
    DWORD rsize = (w * sizeof(PIX) + 3) / 4 * 4;
    DWORD pad = rsize - w * sizeof(PIX);
    DWORD rawsize = rsize * h * sizeof(PIX);
    BYTE zero[3] = {0};
    const char *id = "BM";

    BMP bmp = {
        2 + sizeof(BMP) + sizeof(DIB) + rawsize, 
        0,
        2 + sizeof(BMP) + sizeof(DIB)
    };

    DIB dib = {
        sizeof(DIB),
        w,
        h,
        1,
        24,
        0,
        rawsize,
        2835,
        2835,
        0,
        0
    };
    PIX pix = {b, g, r};
    int i, j;

    fp = fopen(fn, "wb");
    fwrite(id, 1, 2, fp);
    fwrite(&bmp, 1, sizeof(bmp), fp);
    fwrite(&dib, 1, sizeof(dib), fp);

    for(i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            fwrite(&pix, sizeof(pix), 1, fp);
        }
        if (pad) fwrite(zero, 1, pad, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

(The `.bmp` suffix has to be added by the caller. Also note how the BM marker is written separately from the rest of the `BMP` struct.)

Comment: Just so to mention im using really ancient compiler and i dont know if it is even under C89 and uint32 is not included.

Comment: Changing from BYTE to DWORD work'd only for the width. If i do that with the height it don't draw the image.

Comment: The integer types with fixed length are defined in `<stdint.h>`. But since you are on Windows, you can use `DWORD` instead of ´uint32_t` and `WORD` instead of `uint16_t`.

Comment: Yes i got that :). But the height still don't want to come out.
Messing with height more then `214` leeds to damaged bmp.

Comment: But that hasn't anything to do with the incorrect height in the struct field. Your memory allocation and also the way how you write out the data are not correct. I'll update my answer

Comment: I have to say that there are no compiler options avaiable since im doing this on closed platform under SDL. The output of my code is full colored bmp with the size of 500x214. (the height must be 460 h/e) But everything else seems to work. Im just curious where i have to call the padding function you mention i forgot to call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code I posted doesn't rely on compiler options; I just wanted to mention it. The created bitmap is technical full RGB colour, but it just uses a single colour. (I've taken all settings from your code.) The padding goes at the end of each line to make the raw data for that line a multiple of 4 bytes. Look at `if (pad) ...` in my example.

Comment: Allright, i will try this.. seems you are very inside the things.
I wrote my function advanced because i will need the full potential of 16M colors. (writing something like paint).
Thanks = )

Comment: Hmm it doesn't allow me to use the BMP/DIB arrays like that.
Says illegal adress operation on lines:`
`2 + sizeof(DIB) + rawsize`
`w,`
`PIX pix[] = {*B, *G, *R};`

Comment: If you can't initialise structures - which compiler _are_ you using? - you must rewrite the code the way you has it before: Declare the variable without initialisation and then assign values to the fields. It migt be a good idea to zero out the memory with `memset` before assigning data to the fields.

Comment: The compiler of an game Engine called gameEditor.
I can make arrays like:
`int array[] = {3, 2, 5};`
but not like:
`int array = {3, 2, 5};`

Comment: The second example you've posted is not a valid array, just a scalar integer. But you should be able to initialise structures like arrays, only with different data types per field. Now that I look at your comment, I see that you dereference pointers. Might that be your error?

Comment: Yes i can make arrays of structs/arrays of struct pointers etc.
Its just the values w / (the size) ..they give such error.
I see on your code you use BMP/DIB/PIX to make the array.. but you didn't said where/how are they declared. I assume BMP is `unsigned long` as well as DIB and PIX is `unsigned char` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The code wasn't supposed to be standalone. These structures are the same as in your original code. Just copy those. (But you must remove the file mark `bmp_type` from `BMP`.)

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry: When I said the structs are the same you used, I was wrong. They are your structs with every `x[2]` replaced by `WORD x` and every `x[4]` replaced by `DWORD x`. I'm sorry about that. (I'd post the whole code, but I can't acces it right now.) What ahhepns in your example seems to be a byte truncation.

Comment: Hello, started from the beginning, made a clean code and i succeed printing 673 KB bmp with the expected 500x460 res. and green color. The only problem i found.. and the only problem why your code directly couldn't work is that my compiler don't allow using other vars as a value of a struct member in array.
llegal:
`BMP bmp[] = { 70, 0, 0, 54 };`
Illegal (pseudo code to save space):
`BMP bmp[] = { sizeof(), 0, 0, sizeof());`
If i do it on the illegal way.. it says "Illegal Adress Operation".
So don't post anything as i already got my errors :) Thanks to you i freshed my memory.. one more last.

Comment: .. one more last thing to try to take care of.. to get everything fully working as i expected. Excuse my grammatical errors please. I am apparently not very good in English. Gladly you could easily understand me tho.

Answer (score 0):

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqxO9.png (happans each time with different colors)
Current code:

```
typedef unsigned char  BYTE;    //1
typedef unsigned short WORD;    //2
typedef unsigned long  DWORD;   //4

typedef struct BMP_HEADER
{
    BYTE bmp_size[4];       //4

    BYTE bmp_as[4];         //4

    BYTE bmp_offset[4];     //4
} BMP;

typedef struct DIB_HEADER
{
    BYTE dib_size[4];           //4
    DWORD dib_w;                //4
    BYTE dib_h[4];              //4

    BYTE dib_BMPcplanes[2];     //2
    BYTE dib_BMPBpix[2];            //2
    BYTE dib_BIRGB[4];          //4
    BYTE dib_rawsize[4];        //4

    BYTE dib_Xresolution[4];    //4
    BYTE dib_Yresolution[4];    //4

    BYTE dib_cpalette[4];       //4
    BYTE dib_cimportant[4];     //4
} DIB;

//_______________________________________________________________________________________________//
typedef struct PIXEL_ARRAY
{
    BYTE BGR[3];            //3
} PIX;

BYTE* PAD;
DWORD padding(DWORD w)
{
    int pitch = w * 3;

    if (pitch % 4 != 0)
    {
        pitch += 4 - (pitch % 4);
    }

    return pitch - (w * 3);
}

DWORD row_sz(WORD BMPBpix, DWORD w)
{
    return ((BMPBpix*w+31)/32)*4;
}

void create_bmp(char BMPname[], DWORD w, DWORD h, BYTE R, BYTE G, BYTE B)
{
    // variables
    char build_name[256];
    FILE* fp;

    BMP newBMP;
    DIB newDIB;
    PIX* pix;

    DWORD rsize = (w * sizeof(PIX) + 3) / 4 * 4;
    DWORD pad = rsize - w * sizeof(PIX);
    DWORD rawsize = rsize * h * sizeof(PIX);
    BYTE zero[3] = {0};
    const char *id = "BM";
    int i, j;

    gedMaxGameMem = 2827465479;
    if(w > 1 && h > 1) pix = (PIX*)malloc(w*h);
    else pix = (PIX*)malloc(sizeof(PIX*)*max(w, h));

    // make file
    sprintf(build_name, "%s.bmp", BMPname);
    fp = fopen(build_name, "wb");

    // BM
    fwrite(id, 1, 2, fp);

    // SIZE
    newBMP.bmp_size[0] = (sizeof(newBMP) + sizeof(newDIB) + sizeof(pix));
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_size, 1, 4, fp);

    // Application specifics
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_as, 1, 4, fp);

    // offset
    newBMP.bmp_offset[0] = (sizeof(newBMP) + sizeof(newDIB));
    fwrite(&newBMP.bmp_offset, 1, 4, fp);

    //

    // DIB SIZE
    newDIB.dib_size[0] = sizeof(newDIB);
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_size, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Image width
    newDIB.dib_w = w;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_w, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Image height
    newDIB.dib_h[0] = h;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_h, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Color planes
    newDIB.dib_BMPcplanes[0] = 1;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPcplanes, 1, 2, fp);

    // DIB BMP Bits per pixel
    newDIB.dib_BMPBpix[0] = 24;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BMPBpix, 1, 2, fp);

    // DIB Compression method
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_BIRGB, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Raw size
    newDIB.dib_rawsize[0] = sizeof(pix);
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_rawsize, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Xresolution
    newDIB.dib_Xresolution[0] = 19;
    newDIB.dib_Xresolution[1] = 11;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_Xresolution, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Yresolution
    newDIB.dib_Yresolution[0] = 19;
    newDIB.dib_Yresolution[1] = 11;
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_Yresolution, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Colors palette
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_cpalette, 1, 4, fp);

    // DIB Important colors
    fwrite(&newDIB.dib_cimportant, 1, 4, fp);

    //

    for(i = 0; i < h; i++) 
    {
        for(j = 0; j < w; j++) 
        {
            fwrite(&pix, sizeof(pix), 1, fp);
        }
        if (pad) fwrite(zero, 1, pad, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```